# Alfresco permission of deployed custom workflow

Tags: workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

### How can i set the permission of a custom worflow?

I deployed a BPMN 2.0 workflow, by placing the bpmn20.xml in `/alfresco/extension` and also using the following `workflow-context.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans>
    <bean id="acme.workflowBootstrap" parent="workflowDeployer">
    <property name="workflowDefinitions">
      <list>
        <props>
          <prop key="engineId">activiti</prop>
          <prop key="location">alfresco/extension/workflows/activiti/superflow.bpmn20.xml</prop>
          <prop key="mimetype">text/xml</prop>
          <prop key="redeploy">false</prop>         
        </props>
      </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The workflow can by found in the Worfkflow console and can be run.

The problem remaing is, that I can only see this worfklow as `admin` in alfresco share. Not as `admin@acme`.

How can I set permission to use this workflow as different user than admin?

Comment: Not sure I understand this correctly, do you mean you can view/select the workflow on http://<host>share/page/site/<sitename>/start-workflow when logged in as admin, but not when you are logged in as a user with less permissions? Which permissions does this user have on the document you are trying to start a workflow on? (does the start workflow action appear for both users? if not the user may just be missing write access )

Comment: @StefanDeLaet Thank you very much for your feedback. For clarification: I can only see my custom workflow under "start new workflow" when I'am logged in as "admin". When I log in as any other user I can not see the workflow. And I'am not sure where to set the permission/visibility of a workflow

Comment: I think that with an out of the box alfresco, there is no such thing like workflow permissions, hence my confusion. I am aware of an alfresco add-on which I have used in order to achieve this (https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/workflow-permissions ) , but I suppose you are not using that.

Comment: You can try debugging front end components\workflow\start-workflow.js and the corresponding back end webscript start-workflow.get.js

Comment: @StefanDeLaet thank you so much for your feedback! I found that plugin while researching. But I must be able to manually archive, what the plugin can do. I'am just curious which layer may modify the visibility. I will now try what workflows are visible using the activiti java api. It's interesting to know, if this is a share configuration (but where is it?) or if this is reaching deeper from the permission aspect.

Comment: it s a share configuration , see answer below

Answer (score 2):

There is an alfresco extension project available to achieve workflow permissions https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/workflow-permissions

Configuration is done in your share custom config, using the elelement "permission-workflows" like this :

> ```
>      <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Workflow">
>
>
>               <!-- A list of workflow definitions that are NOT displayed 
>               <hidden-workflows>
>                   <!-- Hide all WCM related workflows -->
>                   <workflow name="jbpm$wcmwf:*" />
>                   <workflow name="jbpm$wf:*" />
>                   <workflow name="activiti$activiti*" />
>                   <workflow name="activiti$quickStart*" />
>               </hidden-workflows>
>
>               <!-- A list of workflow tasks that are NOT displayed inShare -->
>               <hidden-tasks>
>                   <!-- Hide all WCM related tasks -->
>                   <task type="wcmwf:*" />
>               </hidden-tasks>
>
>               <permission-workflows default="allow">
>                   <permission-workflow name="activiti$epubcreate">
>                       <authorities>
>                           <authority type="group">GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS</authority>                               
>                       </authorities>
>                   </permission-workflow>
>               </permission-workflows>
>           </config>
> ```

Comment: Sorry for my late feedback. I was leaving out one essential information from my question. I use a multi tenant alfresco, and the newly added workflows were only visible for the system user (admin). After getting more into the topic I found this Bug Ticket: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-17885 which describes that newly added worflows are only visible to tenants created after the deployment of the workflow. I was able to fix my problem temporarily by deploying in the workflow console. My assumption of this being a permission problem was wrong. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really speak to how much of the Activiti engine that is bundled with Alfresco is actually exposed. But in the stand alone Activiti product you can assign "candidate starters" to any process.

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_add_a_candidate_starter_to_a_process_definition

This uses the identityLinks mechanism that is also available for tasks, instances and executions.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Maybe my question is unclear because I don't really understand my problem by now. I will consider your answer while my research and will get to you asap. Sorry if my question is unclear, because the problem I'am facing is not default behavior and caused by my self.